# Local minimum of an analytic function

Tags: maxima-minima, analytic-functions, positive-semidefinite, hessian-matrix

This is a follow-up to [a previous question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2847713/local-minimum-has-neighbourhood-with-positive-semi-definite-hessian). I know that any local minimum $x_0$ of a function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has positive semi-definite Hessian $H(x_0) \succeq 0$. **If $f$ is analytic**, can we say moreover that there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $x_0$ such that
$$ H(x) \succeq 0 $$
for all $x \in U$? I don't see any reason for this being true since positive semi-definiteness is not a continuous property (while positive definiteness is), but can't find a counter-example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very simple counter-example: $$f(x)=x^2y^2.$$
This gives $$H(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix} 2y^2&4xy\\ 4xy&2x^2 \end{pmatrix},$$
in particular $$H(x,x)=2x^2\begin{pmatrix} 1&2\\ 2&1 \end{pmatrix},$$
which is not positive semidefinite for $ x \ne 0$.

Comment: Simple and elegant answer... Thank you Harald.

Comment: You're welcome. And if you should want a function with a *strict* local minimum, just add a small multiple of $x^4+y^4$.